# why coinbase callback url not working?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, bitcoin

i have the below code for button creation.

```
public function createButton($name, $price, $currency, $custom=null, $options=array(),$callback)
{
   // $callback=$this->generateReceiveAddress("http://www.tgigo.com");

    // print_r($callback);exit;

    $params = array(
        "name" => $name,
        "price_string" => $price,
        "price_currency_iso" => $currency,
        "callback_url"=>"http://www.tgigo.com"
    );
    if($custom !== null) {
        $params['custom'] = $custom;
    }
    foreach($options as $option => $value) {
        $params[$option] = $value;
    }

    return $this->createButtonWithOptions($params);
}

public function createButtonWithOptions($options=array())
{

    $response = $this->post("buttons", array( "button" => $options ));

    if(!$response->success) {
        return $response;
    }

    $returnValue = new stdClass();
    $returnValue->button = $response->button;
    $returnValue->embedHtml = "<div class=\"coinbase-button\" data-code=\"" . $response->button->code . "\"></div><script src=\"https://coinbase.com/assets/button.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>";
    $returnValue->success = true;


    return $returnValue;
}
```

and i have the below response for above code.

{"success":true,"button":{"code":"675cda22e31b314db557f0538f8ad27e","type":"buy_now","style":"buy_now_large","text":"Pay With Bitcoin","name":"Your Order #1234","description":"1 widget at $100","custom":"my custom tracking code for this order","callback_url":"http://www.tgigo.com","price":{"cents":100000,"currency_iso":"BTC"}}}

using this code payment process completed,but not redirected to the call back url.
any one please help me.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score -1):

The callback_url parameter is for a callback that receives a POST request behind the scenes when payment is complete. The user's browser is not redirected there. You probably want success_url.

https://coinbase.com/api/doc/1.0/buttons/create.html